# Serverless Offline Start

Tags: node.js, serverless

While start the nodejs lambda function by serverless offline, i am getting the below error

command : serverless offline start

**Error:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'R:Projects<project>\node_modules' -> 'R:Projects<project>.build\node_modules'**

Please help to resolve the issue, searching for the solution since two days.

Comment: Welcome. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921598/19330634) help you ?

Comment: @l-_-l, i have checked my configurations, nothing i missed.

Comment: Could you provide your code ? Maybe with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?